# JavaScript tells that PHP sent the email but i dont receive it

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

Hello i am a noob to php and web desing in general,english is not my mother languange so excuse me on my spelling or grammar mistakes.

I am doing a project which is about competitive programing

I have a made a form:
http://takmicarskoprogramiranje.comuf.com/kontakt.html

as you see when you send a message,javascript alerts that email has been send but i dont receive it in my email(contact.php is in the same folder,the hosting site has php installed)

Here is the code for the html and php:
HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
            Your name<br>
            <input type ="text" name ="cf_name"><br>
            Your e-mail<br>
            <input type ="text" name ="cf_email"><br>

            Message<br>
            <textarea name = "cf_message"></textarea><br>

            <input type="submit" value ="Send">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'takmicarsko.programiranje@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Poruka od posjetioca site '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'kontakt.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to takmicarsko.programiranje@yahoo.com');
        window.location = 'kontakt.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check your spam ? You're sending, from a website, a mail with "From" from a different domain. It is possible that your mail think this is spam.

Comment: it is empty :/ thank you for the response :) @dievardump so you recommend me to create a email to send from?

Comment: Is your environment correctly setup ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php))?

Comment: All i did is open up account i didnt do anything in the cPanel i just uploaded files

Answer (score 1):

In email header `From` should have your email. not users email

```
$headers = "From: mail@takmicarskoprogramiranje.comuf.com\r\n";
```

**UPDATE**

Add following headers

```
$headers = "Content-type:text/plain" . "\r\n";
```

so it should look like this

```
$headers = "Content-type:text/plain" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: mail@takmicarskoprogramiranje.comuf.com\r\n";
```

**FINAL**

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
$mail_to = 'takmicarsko.programiranje@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Poruka od posjetioca site '.$field_name;
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
$headers = "Content-type:text/plain" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: mail@takmicarskoprogramiranje.comuf.com\r\n';
$headers .= 'Reply-To: mail@takmicarskoprogramiranje.comuf.com\r\n';
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
if (!$mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to takmicarsko.programiranje@yahoo.com');
    window.location = 'kontakt.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'kontakt.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Changed it,still doesnt work.Thank you for noticing :)

Comment: are yo checking `takmicarsko.programiranje@yahoo.com` account's inbox??

Comment: i changed reply to header as well,and yes i am checking the inbox and the spam

Comment: Doesnt work,the web host support mail() so that isnt the problem,ill be searching the web,thank for trying to help

Comment: Give it a last try.. Remove `\n` from `$body_message`

Comment: doesnt work but thanks again